# GLSL strange compilation errors

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, shader, lwjgl

I have searched on the web but cannot find the reason why it is doing this. I have my vertex and fragment shaders here:

```
// Vertex Shader
#version 150 core

in vec3 position;

out vec3 color;

void main(void) {

gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position,y, position.z, 1.0);

color = vec3(position.x + 1.0, position,y + 1.0, position.z + 1.0);

}
```

And:

```
//Fragment Shader
#version 150 core

in vec3 color;

out vec4 finalColor;

void main(void) {

finalColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

}
```

I looked over it several times and while it serves no real purpose as a shader it still doesn't have any visible errors in the code. Whe I try to compile it I get the following error:

> ERROR: 0:5: 'y' : undeclared identifier
>
> ERROR: 0:5: 'constructor' : too many arguments
>
> ERROR: 0:6: 'constructor' : too many arguments
>   Strange enough I get the error on either the vertex or fragment shader depending on which one I plug into `glCompileShader()`first. I have tried swapping version numbers but it didn't work and I no longer feel like programming today >.>

Answer (score 4):

position **,** y lol. You have a comma instead of a period. it should be position**.**y.

Comment: You have it in the color = vec3(position.x + 1.0, position,y + 1.0, position.z + 1.0); part too lol.

Comment: you wouldn't believe the struggle and debugging to find out it was just comma in place of a period. I literally scanned the spelling repeatedly but it wasn't the spelling that was the issue!

Comment: Lol we all get these dumb problems from time to time :D